# Use a list of single threaded objects in a parallel processing loop

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Suppose I process 1000 items in a parallel processing loop.
Processing an item sometimes needs a `Calculation` object with a specialized algoritm which is required to be single-threaded and is somewhat expensive to create.

I was considering creating a container class with a `List<Calculation>` that can be asked to give one such object when it is free, or otherwise create a new `Calculation` object.

The administration inside the container class must be coded manually and must be proof against errors in different threads, so I thought there might be some glitch easily overlooked.

Are there any C# patterns or types for this scenario that you know of?

Comment: Why not create a `Calculation` object for each item to process?

Comment: I feel it would be overkill, but technically ok I agree.

Comment: From the docs: [Create an object pool by using a ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-create-an-object-pool)

Answer (score 2):

This is called an object pool. It is useful if creating or destroying objects is costly and there are opportunities for reuse.

You can operate the pool manually. Take items when needed and return them after use. This is prone to bugs. You can forget to return items (leaving them to the GC possibly holding up resources such as file handles). You can also return early which will cause two consumers of the pool to operate on the same object concurrently.

You can also use [object resurrection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clyon/2006/04/25/object-resurrection/) to determine when an items was dropped and automatically pull it into the pool. In my opinion this does not work in practice. Depending on GC behavior this can lead to huge swings in resource consumption. There is a lot of potential for very bad bugs as well.

In all likelihood you will simply need to use the object pool correctly. A pattern like

```
var obj = pool.Take();
try {
 Use(obj);
}
finally {
 pool.Return(obj);
}
```

comes to mind. You can also use `using` for this.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this kind of thread pool successfully by using a ConcurrentBag collection rather than a list. It's thread-safe. Something  like this:

```
  ConcurrentBag<Calculation> idle = new ConcurrentBag<Calculation>();

  Calculation calc;
  if ( idle.IsEmpty || !idle.TryTake(calc)) {
       calc = new Calculation();
  }

  /* start the Calculation object */
  /* when it completes toss it in the bag for reuse ... */
  idle.Add (calc);
```

A Bag is like a list but unordered. That's fine for what you want to do.